# Driver verifier won't produce a dump file

Tags: windows, windows-10, bsod, microsoft-driver-verifier

I'm trying to use driver verifier to detect problematic drivers on my pc however I'm stuck in a GSOD with the following message.

DRIVER VERIFIER DETECTED VIOLATION

The problem is that the dump gets stuck at 0 percent complete

There's no dump created so how do I identify the offending driver?

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately without a dump file you won’t be able to analyze the file to determine the problem.  The only way to generate the file is to determine the reason its not being generated.  One way to do that is to reinstall Windows 10, on a stable branch, and attempt to recreate the BSOD and see if that makes a difference

Comment: Is there a manufacturer's driver update app for your computer? Can you restart in Safe Mode and run the Driver Verifier that way?

Comment: @Ramhound Unfortunately I had the same issue on a stable branch with driver verifier that's why I was hoping there was more I could do to determine the faulty driver.

Comment: @John I think you missed the point of the question. I can run driver verifier and all my drivers are up to date however a driver is faulty and won't work correctly on my PC. I'm trying to determine which is the problematic driver. In safe mode everything works because the driver is not loaded.

Comment: Compare Device Manager in Safe Mode with Device Manager in Normal mode. It may be the Network driver (not loaded unless you start Safe Mode with Networking) or Video (because Safe Mode starts in VGA).